# Button moves when text is long

Tags: javascript, css

I created 2 buttons, the first with short text, and the other one with long text, but this is not aligned.

How to align the second button when text is long?

https://jsfiddle.net/ws2awc03/

```
var btn = document.createElement("button");
var btn2 = document.createElement("button");
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

btn.style.width = "200px";
btn.style.height = "150px";
btn.style.margin = "10px";
btn.innerHTML = "text";
body.appendChild(btn);

btn2.style.width = "200px";
btn2.style.height = "150px";
btn.style.margin = "10px";
btn2.innerHTML = "text text text text text text text text text text text text text";
body.appendChild(btn2);
```

*This is an example. The real case has a matrix (10x7 buttons).

Comment: [Here you find a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DomeTune/ws2awc03/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the vertical alignment to middle:

```
button {
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2w955o1v/)**

The default vertical alignment for inline elements is baseline, which is what you saw.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled the button 2 margin : `btn.style.margin = "10px";`.
You can define the behavior of the parent element, in this case `body` with `body.style.display = "flex";`.